# ¿Cómo utilizo las funciones de arreglos y llamarlos al presionar un botón en una interfaz de tienda virtual?

Tags: java, array, funciones, java-swing

Al presionar el botón "comprar" se ejecuta unas funciones de arreglos al comprar unos productos. El primer método debería guardar en un arreglo las cantidades de cada producto comprado. El segundo método, en un arreglo bidimensional el nombre de los productos y su precio. Y el tercer método ejecutar la operación para guardar el resultado en un mensaje. Pero al presionar el botón me sale mi panel donde iría el mensaje pero esta vacio y sale el error

> NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.trim()" because "in" is null.

No entiendo porqué ayudaa, he tratado.

[image: Interfaz con los nombres de variable de cada componente]

```
public class Ejercicio6_Principal extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    double base = 0.0, total = 0.0;
    String salida = "";
    
    public Ejercicio6_Principal() {
        initComponents();
    }

    //Aquí empieza mi dolor de cabeza
    private void btnCompraActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        if(!scroll.isVisible()){
            scroll.setVisible(true);
        } else{
            scroll.setVisible(false);
        }
        
        int m = 6, n = 2;
        double a[], c[];
        String b[][];
        
        a = new double [m];
        b = new String [m][n];
        c = new double [m];
        
        leerCantidades(a);
        leerPrecios(b);
        PagaTotal(a, b, c);
        
        txaResultado.setText(salida);
    }

    private void leerCantidades (double cantidades[]){
        String[] evaluacion = new String[6];
        
        evaluacion[0] = txtCant1.getText();
        evaluacion[1] = txtCant2.getText();
        evaluacion[2] = txtCant3.getText();
        evaluacion[3] = txtCant4.getText();
        evaluacion[4] = txtCant5.getText();
        evaluacion[5] = txtCant6.getText();
        
        cantidades = new double[evaluacion.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){ //Por si hay un espacio vacio, convertirlo a 0.0
            if(evaluacion[i].equals("")){ //así no se altera la operación cant x precio
                evaluacion[i] = "0.0";
            }
            cantidades[i] = Double.parseDouble(evaluacion[i]);
        }
    }
    
    private void leerPrecios (String precios[][]){
        precios = new String[6][2];
        
        precios[0][1]= etiPrecio1.getText();
        precios[1][1]= etiPrecio2.getText();
        precios[2][1]= etiPrecio3.getText();
        precios[3][1]= etiPrecio4.getText();
        precios[4][1]= etiPrecio5.getText();
        precios[5][1]= etiPrecio6.getText();
        
        precios[0][0]= etiProducto1.getText();
        precios[1][0]= etiProducto2.getText();
        precios[2][0]= etiProducto3.getText();
        precios[3][0]= etiProducto4.getText();
        precios[4][0]= etiProducto5.getText();
        precios[5][0]= etiProducto6.getText();
    }
    
    private void PagaTotal (double a[], String b[][], double c[]){
        double[] e = new double[6];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            c[i] = a[i] * Double.parseDouble(b[i][1]);
            base += c[i];
            
            for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
                if(c[j] != 0.0){
                    e[j] = c[j];
                }
            }
        }
        total = base + (base * 0.18);
        salida = "\tPAGA TOTAL:\n -SubTotal: "+base + "\n -Paga Final: " + total+ "\n\tUNITARIOS:\n";
        
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
                if(a[i] != 0){
                    salida += b[i][0] + "\n -Precio: S/."+b[i][1] + "\n -Paga: S/." + e[i]+"\n";
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: en tu codigo no hay ninguna llamada a trim. asegurate de tener siempre un [mcve]

Comment: Los errores suelen ser más extensos y decir en qué lugar ocurren. Incluye esa información en la pregunta al menos.

Comment: El problema surge en private void pagatotal, porque eliminando los for y dejando solo la asignación del texto a "salida" al presionar el botón si aparece el mensaje en text area. Mi primer for debería calcular el precio base multiplicando la cantidad con su precio correspondiente y asignarle esa suma a la variable base para luego sacarle su igv. El segundo for sería un filtro para pasar las cantidades que estoy comprando a una arreglo y quitar los que no estoy comprando. El tercer for es un filtro para que solo me aparezca los productos con sus cantidades que estoy comprando pero no funcionan.

Comment: xq no usas arrayList no seria mas coodo?

Answer (score 0):

Tu código tiene un solo e inocente problema, aunque fatal: creas dos arrays (a y b), los instancias en `btnCompraActionPerformed`, y luego dentro de *leerPrecios* creas otro que reemplaza a *b*, entonces cuando el programa llega a *PagaTotal* se encuentra con un array *b* vacío, lo que lanza una excepción. Solo tienes que quitar `precios = new String[6][2];` de *leerPrecios* y todo funciona con normalidad.

Te muestro la salida que obtuve:

```
    PAGA TOTAL:

 -SubTotal: 778.17

 -Paga Final: 918.2406

    UNITARIOS:

lenteja

 -Precio: S/.21.10

 -Paga: S/.42.2

azucar

 -Precio: S/.12.23

 -Paga: S/.36.69

leche

 -Precio: S/.43.35

 -Paga: S/.43.35

vino

 -Precio: S/.11.11

 -Paga: S/.255.52999999999997

droga

 -Precio: S/.100.10

 -Paga: S/.400.4
```